# Cannot connect to a working VPN through Network indicator?

Tags: 13.04, network-manager, indicator, vpn

I have fully calibrated VPN connection with all the required settings but I cannot connect it through Network Indicator. However sometimes it works just fine and I can connect it. What might be the problem, any idea?

Comment: Do you get any error messages at all when you try to do this?

Comment: similar problem: when I connect at home (for testing) one laptop to my daemon server pptpd via my PRIVATE ip address there is no problem, but when I try to connect out of my house, sometimes work, sometimes doesn't work.
May that will depend on the Internet Provider's policy? mine is fastweb.

Comment: Exactly same problem right, but I don't think it is about the provider.

Answer (score 1):

When the VPN doesn't connect kindly:

1)Ping the VPN server to ensure it is available.

2) Confirm your Internet provider or your computer's firewall settings are still configured to permit traffic to and from your VPN. If you are using PPTP protocol, TCP Port 1723 and GRE Protocol 47 must be opened/enabled and for L2TP ensure UDP port 1701 is not blocked.

3) Confirm that the ISP or firewall settings will allow traffic on UDP ports 500 and 4500 if using IKEv2 for the VPN tunnel.

Hope it could help to narrow down the diagnosis.